# How to kill stubborn process

Tags: process, kill

I've an annoying process that won't die:

```
ps -A | grep "nzbget"
```

gives me:

```
11394 pts/3    00:00:00 nzbget
```

If I try:

```
pkill nzbget (or 11394)
```

...I get no response and the process is still alive, top gives me:

```
PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
11394 asystem+  20   0  125448   6244   4984 T   0.0  0.1   0:00.00 nzbget
```

I run nzbget with 'nzbget -s', if I do this after it is running (and I've tried to stop it), I get a [binding socket failed] error and all I can do is reboot.

How can I kill this off without rebooting?

Comment: I might possibly have just forgot to use sudo/su, as I didn't get a response, I just presumed it had worked ok (or not had errors).  Just did [sudo kill -9 nzbget] and it responded with [[2]+  Killed                  nzbget -s.]  So all good.

Comment: By the way, it is very easy to write unkillable process. For example, simple `try: pass except: pass` in loop in Python becomes an unkillable process. To stop them, use `kill -9` or `killall -s SIGKILL dude` or `pkill -9 dude`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `kill -9 11394` to kill the process completely ungracefully, this will invoke the following:

From [The 3 most important "kill" signals on the Linux/UNIX command line](http://meinit.nl/the-3-most-important-kill-signals-on-the-linux-unix-command-line):

> The kernel will let go of the process without informing the process of it. An unclean kill like this could result in data loss. This is the "hardest", "roughest" and most unsafe kill signal available, and should only be used to stop something that seems unstoppable.

Answer (score 9):

As the process is stopped* (notice the `T` as the state output in `top`), it is unable to do any signal handling at all. So, you need to use a signal that does not require process interaction, in your case `SIGKILL` (9) as in the following

```
kill -9 11394
```

If you want, for whatever reason, get a core dump of the process (and your system is configured for that), you could use `SIGSEGV` (11) instead. This does not require any process interaction either.

* I assume stopped here, because a traced process should be able to handle signals, which may lead to the process being stopped.

Comment: +1: The only answer (so far) to recognise the T state of the process. You could also send a SIGCONT to the process and any queued signals will be delivered. i.e. if you've already run pkill (and sent a SIGTERM), if you then send a SIGCONT, the process will be started and the SIGTERM will be delivered.

Comment: @camh your comment is the only answer to correctly mention `SIGCONT`. Please post this as a separate answer ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Try using the signal flag to gracefully kill the process:

`kill -15 11394`

Answer (score 1):

There are various signals you can try, which I am sure someone else will list, but the one I find most effective is the `HUP` signal:

```
kill -hup 11394
```

I find this works in a lot of cases where the application isn't responding to any other signals. Failing that you can just do `kill -9`, though this may have side effects since it just pulls the plug and doesn't let the application clean up.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of an X app, I have had luck using  xkill and clicking its window when the app wouldn't respond to a kill from the command line